# How do higher-order derivative terms appear/get suppressed when renormalizing Lagrangian of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization

As the title says, I learned/read different methods of regularization/renormalization in QFT, but I am not sure if I really saw renormalization methods that involve higher-order derivative terms in Lagrangian. I want to know an example where such a method is used to renormalize a QFT.

Comment: Well, to be fair, one has that the maximum physical degree of partial derivative must be 2. This has to do with causality required by SR in 4D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During Wilsonian RG flow, higher-order derivatives are generically generated (as long as they don't break space-time symmetries), much in the same way that higher order interactions are generated. This can be clearly seen in computing a one-loop self-energy correction, which will generate all powers of momentum-square as a correction to the bare inverse propagator.

In this kind of RG (and its generalizations), it is important to keep higher order derivative terms to compute accurately critical exponents, for instance. See for example [arXiv:0302.227](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0302227), where derivatives up to order $4$ are kept.

These terms tend to be neglected since they are typically irrelevant at low energy compared to the lowest order in momenta. However, this is not necessarily the case for all QFTs, as it might happen that for some specific critical points, the lowest order derivatives vanishes dynamically during the flow, and thus the next lowest order is needed.